# re module and tkinter entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a program where the user can input a query into an entry widget which I have set up. I need to use a text file to scan for a specific word that they enter, I know how to do that. My question is how can I get the user to enter the query into the entry widget and then use the regular expression module to scan if that word is in the text file and then output the solution.

Comment: You don't need a regex unless you are going to be using word boundaries

Answer (score 1):

Use `re.search()` to look for `word` in the file content (`_file.read()`):

```
word = entry.get()
if re.search(word, _file.read()):
    # Your code
```

**Edit:**

```
word = password.get()
fileopen = open('phone.txt')
for line in fileopen.readlines():
    if re.search(word, line):
        #You code
        fileopen.close()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

use a Entry.get() method to read the entry to get a regular expression and then just use the string as a pattern.
If the tool is intended for people with less or no experience with regular expressions I add replace `*` with `.*` so that they just use asterisk as a wild card or you can also replace `?` with `.` 
If the audience is supposed to be experienced, just use what you got from Entry.

Comment: I'm using the re module to `.readlines()` of the input in the entry widget